# Django-simple-captcha failed to load given url

Tags: django, captcha

I have installed django-simple-captcha as it is described in tutorial. Captcha is working fine in development environment, but in production I don't see captcha's image. The url of captcha is not accessible though urls.py is correct. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`./manage.py test captcha`
on both.

I think you'll get the error
`ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed`
in your production environment.

It's because your installed PIL or Pillow was compiled without libfreetype.

Comment: Thanks! It could help if no PIL or Pillow is installed, but it was not my case. In my case, the problem was actually that I had a debug print line in manage.py. After I deleted it everything worked fine!